# Interactive script on stop systemd service

Tags: linux, io, sh, systemd

I need to run script when system shutting down (reboot...) that asks user for contributing some actions:

```bash
#!/bin/bash 
tty
echo ARE YOU SURE?:  
read test 
echo $test
```

```systemd
[Unit] 
Description= Minetest server 

[Service] 
StandardInput=tty-force
ExecStart= /bin/true
ExecStop=/home/user/test.sh
Type=oneshot

StandardInput=tty
StandardOutput=tty
TTYPath=/dev/tty8
TTYReset=yes
TTYVHangup=yes
RemainAfterExit=true
```

If I'm executing it as ExecStop, I have output like:

```
not a tty 
INPUT TEST:
```

and no ask for input

Whats wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

the ExecStop is called by another script ,not from your console, so there is no tty device attached
and the built-in command read requires input to be a tty device

btw ,  asking user to contribute via a script is fragile and uncontrollable

Comment: ExecStart is working. ExecStopPost is working.

ExecStop not working